# Underscore and Mongoose: Use document as outer function's return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm trying to use Mongoose and Underscore together, to do something like this:

```
var person_ids = [1, 2, 3];

var persons = _(person_ids).map(function(id) {
    Person.findById(id, function(person) { // Non-blocking
        // How do I use 'person' as the outer function's return value?
    });
});
```

Is there any way to do this? I realize I may be trying to force a synchronous paradigm on a library designed to be used asynchronously.

Comment: Didn't know that `findById` was async. Looks like you're stuck in a twisted maze of callbacks then. Try the `Person.find` approach though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only way you can get value is by callback:

check my answer at:
[How to retrieve value of a variable in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945527/how-to-retrieve-value-of-a-variable-in-class/7945824#7945824)

important places in code are:

```
Place.getActualId(function(id){ console.log(id); });
```

and

```
 getActualId: function(callback){
       this.find({where: {actual: 1}}).on('success', function(placeTmp){
       callback(placeTmp['id']);
 })
```

Comment: Yeah, this was my understanding of how the Mongoose library works. It's disappointing to find out that it isn't at all compatible with the functions provided by Underscore, though.